# aumentar la cantida de usuarios para este programa

Tags: java, eclipse

Tengo el siguiente código el cual solo está para que una sola persona se registre, la duda sería como hacer para que mínimo 2 personas se puedan registrar en este programa y queden guardados los datos de cada cliente.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Cajero {
    static boolean validar_contraseña(int contraseña) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int cl, cl1, intentos=0;
        boolean valor_retorno;

        do {
            System.out.println ("Ingrese contraseña:");
            cl1 = sc.nextInt();

            if (cl1==contraseña) {   
                System.out.println ("Contraseña aceptada...");
                valor_retorno = true;
                intentos=3;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println ("La contraseña ingresada no corresponde a la cuenta. Intente de nuevo..");
                intentos++;
                valor_retorno = false;
            }
        } while (intentos<3);
        return valor_retorno;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random  rnd = new Random();

        boolean resp;
        String documento;
        int cl1=0;
        int cl2=0;
        double consignacion = 0;
        String contraseña="";
        int nocuenta=0;
        String cuenta="";
        String[][] cuentas = new String[5][5];
        //varchar cuentas[][];
        int i=0;
        int op=0;
        int op1=0;
        double retiro = 0;
        double saldo = 0;
        String nombre="";

        do {
            System.out.println ("\n\n");

            System.out.println ("  Bienvenidos a su Banco PCA  ");
            System.out.println ("      MENU PRINCIPAL      ");
            System.out.println ("        Seleccione:        ");
            System.out.println ("   1-Apertura de cuenta    ");
            System.out.println ("   2-Menu transacciones  ");
            System.out.println ("         3-Salir          ");

            System.out.print ("Seleccione opcion y pulse Enter : ");

            do {
                op = sc.nextInt();
            } while (op<1 && op>3);

            switch (op) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println ("MENU DE APERTURA DE CUENTAS");
                System.out.println ("Ingrese Nombre");
                nombre = sc.next();
                System.out.println ("Ingrese Nro Documento");
                documento  = sc.next();
                do {
                    System.out.println ("Ingrese Clave para su nueva cuenta (Valor numerico)");
                    cl1 = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println ("Ingrese Nuevamente la Clave para su nueva cuenta (Valor numerico)");
                    cl2 = sc.nextInt();
                    if (cl1 != cl2) {
                        System.out.println ("Error en la comprobación de la contraseña.  Intentelo nuevamente...");
                    }
                }while (cl1 != cl2);                  

                nocuenta = rnd.nextInt(100);
                System.out.println ("Ingrese monto deposito inicial:");
                saldo = sc.nextDouble();
                System.out.println ("Sr (a) :"+nombre);
                System.out.println ("Su numero de cuenta es:"+nocuenta);                           
                System.out.println ("Su saldo es:"+saldo);                           
                System.out.println ("Pulse cualquier numero y Enter para continuar...");                           
                op1 = sc.nextInt();
                break;                  
            case 2:
                System.out.println ("\n\n");

                System.out.println ("  Bienvenidos a su Banco PCA  ");
                System.out.println ("      MENU TRANSACCIONES      ");
                System.out.println ("      1-Depositar Dinero:  ");
                System.out.println ("      2-Retirar Dinero    ");
                System.out.println ("      3-Consultar Saldo       ");
                System.out.println ("      4-Cambio de clave       ");
                System.out.println (" 5-Regresar al menu principal ");

                System.out.print ("Digite opcion...:");
                op1 = sc.nextInt();
                switch (op1) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println ("Depositos:");
                    //resp = validar_contraseña(cl1);
                    if (validar_contraseña(cl1)) {
                        System.out.println ("Consignar a la cuenta "+cuenta+" De "+nombre);
                        System.out.println ("Ingrese valor consignación:");
                        consignacion = sc.nextDouble();
                        if (consignacion>0) {
                            saldo = saldo + consignacion;

                            System.out.println ("Su nuevo saldo es de : "+saldo);
                            System.out.println ("Gracias por utilizar nuestros servicios...");
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println ("No se pudo verificar la información suministrada...");
                    }
                    System.out.println ("Pulse cualquier numero y Enter para continuar...");                           
                    op1 = sc.nextInt();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println ("Retiros");
                    if (validar_contraseña(cl1)) {
                        System.out.println ("Ingrese valor a Retirar:");
                        retiro = sc.nextDouble();
                        if (retiro>0) {
                            saldo = saldo - retiro;

                            System.out.println ("Su nuevo saldo es de:"+saldo);
                            System.out.println ("Gracias por utilizar nuestros servicios...");

                            System.out.println ("Pulse cualquier numero y Enter para continuar...");                           
                            op1 = sc.nextInt();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println ("No se pudo verificar la información suministrada...");
                    }
                    break;


                case 3:
                    System.out.println ("Consulta de saldo");
                    if (validar_contraseña(cl1)) {
                        System.out.println ("Su saldo es de:"+saldo);
                        System.out.println ("Gracias por utilizar nuestros servicios...");

                        System.out.println ("Pulse cualquier numero y Enter para continuar...");                           
                        op1 = sc.nextInt();
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println ("No se pudo verificar la información suministrada...");
                    }
                    break;

                case 4:
                    System.out.println ("Cambio de clave");
                    if (validar_contraseña(cl1)) {
                        System.out.println ("Cambio de clave de la cuenta "+nocuenta+" De "+nombre);

                        do {
                            System.out.println ("Ingrese nueva Clave (Valor numerico)");
                            cl1 = sc.nextInt();
                            System.out.println ("Ingrese Nuevamente la nueva Clave (Valor numerico)");
                            cl2 = sc.nextInt();
                            if (cl1 != cl2) {
                                System.out.println ("Error en la comprobación de la contraseña.  Intentelo nuevamente...");
                            }
                        }while (cl1 != cl2);   
                        System.out.println ("Se ha asignado nueva clave a la cuenta ");
                    }
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Transferir dinero a otra cuenta");


                default:
                    System.out.println ("Opcion no valida... Intente nuevamente");
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while(op!=3);
        System.out.println ("Gracias por utilizar nuestros servicios...Hasta Pronto.");
    }   





}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta deja muchas dudas. Puedes explicar mejor qué quieres hacer?. Mínimo 2 cuentas pero, dónde, cómo? a la hora de crear 1 cuenta se debe de informar al usuario de que hace falta otra cuenta para que sean 2? si puedes explicarte más fuera mejor.

Comment: voy a intentar explicarle, este codigo que subi cuando lo ejecuto SOLO me permite crear un usuario, y lo guarda para todas las acciones como retirar, consignar y eso, lo que necesito hacer ahora es que de alguna forma, yo pueda crear un segundo ususario y que ambos usuarios queden guardados para hacer unas interacciones entre ellos, como tranferir dinero de una cuenta a otra, (ese metodo no esta pero una vez tenga al 2 usuario lo hago).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de hacer lo que quieres.

1. Hacer una clase llamada Cuentas con las variables nombre, documento,
   contraseña, clave y número de cuenta. Luego crear una lista de cuentas (usando un List) y poder modificarlas por separado en el programa (con Getters y Setters).
2. Guardar cada cuenta en un `ArrayList` de tipo String o Integer pero, si lo haces
   de esta forma también tendrás que hacer un ArrayList para saldo,
   otro para número de cuenta, etc...
3. También se puede hacer lo mismo con Arrays. Ejemplo: `int[] clave, número de cuenta`, y `String[] nombre, documento`.

La mejor opción de estas tres es la primera. He eliminado parte de tu código para hacerlo más corto y puedas entender los cambios que he hecho pero, cuando entiendas cómo funciona puedes hacer las modificaciones que desees para que todo quede a tu gusto.

Lo único que hice para que lo tengas como ejemplo y puedas hacer las demás opciones de tu menú fue: la clase Cuenta, Apertura de cuenta y Depositar dinero. Ahora mismo se puede crear infinitas cuentas en el programa y se puede depositar dinero a una de ellas. He incluido una nueva opción en el menú llamada `3-Detalles de cuentas existentes` donde podrás ver todos los detalles de todas las cuentas, incluyendo el saldo. Faltaría que modifiques el código para que restes el monto a depositar a otra cuenta y etc... Seguro podrás hacerlo.

Ojo con los comentarios que he dejado.

**Clase Cuenta:**

```
public class Cuenta {

    // Variables
    private int numeroCuenta;
    private String nombre;
    private String documento;
    private double saldo;
    private int clave;

    // Constructor vacío para permitir la instancia
    public Cuenta() {
    }

    // GETTERS
    public int getNumeroCuenta() {
        return numeroCuenta;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public String getDocumento() {
        return documento;
    }
    public double getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }
    public int getClave() {
        return clave;
    }

    // SETTERS
    public void setNumeroCuenta(int numeroCuenta) {
        this.numeroCuenta = numeroCuenta;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public void setDocumento(String documento) {
        this.documento = documento;
    }
    public void setSaldo(double saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }
    public void setClave(int clave) {
        this.clave = clave;
    }
}
```

**Clase principal con el main:** (he agregado los cambios que has solicitado en los comentarios)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rnd = new Random();

        // Clase Cuenta
        Cuenta cuenta;
        // Lista de cuentas
        List<Cuenta> cuentas = new ArrayList<Cuenta>();

        int cl1 = 0;
        int cl2 = 0;
        int op = 0;
        int op1 = 0;
        // He movido algunas declaraciones de variables dentro del switch

        do {
            System.out.println("\n\n");

            System.out.println("  Bienvenidos a su Banco PCA  ");
            System.out.println("      MENU PRINCIPAL      ");
            System.out.println("        Seleccione:        ");
            System.out.println("   1-Apertura de cuenta    ");
            System.out.println("   2-Menu transacciones  ");
            System.out.println("   3-Detalles de cuentas existentes  "); // Nueva opción
            System.out.println("         4-Salir          ");

            System.out.print("Seleccione opcion y pulse Enter : ");

            do {
                op = sc.nextInt();
            } while (op < 1 && op > 3);

            switch (op) {
            case 1: // Apertura de cuenta
                System.out.println("MENU DE APERTURA DE CUENTAS");
                System.out.println("Ingrese Nombre");
                String nombre = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Ingrese Nro Documento");
                String documento = sc.next();
                do {
                    System.out.println("Ingrese Clave para su nueva cuenta (Valor numerico)");
                    cl1 = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Ingrese Nuevamente la Clave para su nueva cuenta (Valor numerico)");
                    cl2 = sc.nextInt();
                    if (cl1 != cl2) {
                        System.out.println("Error en la comprobación de la contraseña.  Intentelo nuevamente...");
                    }
                } while (cl1 != cl2);

                int nocuenta = rnd.nextInt(100);
                System.out.println("Ingrese monto deposito inicial:");
                double saldo = sc.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Sr (a) :" + nombre);
                System.out.println("Su numero de cuenta es:" + nocuenta);
                System.out.println("Su saldo es:" + saldo);
                System.out.println("Pulse cualquier numero y Enter para continuar...");

                // Guardar cuenta
                cuenta = new Cuenta();
                cuenta.setNumeroCuenta(nocuenta);
                cuenta.setNombre(nombre);
                cuenta.setDocumento(documento);
                cuenta.setClave(cl1);
                cuenta.setSaldo(saldo);
                // Agregar a la lista
                cuentas.add(cuenta);

                op1 = sc.nextInt();
                break;
            case 2: // Menu transacciones
                System.out.println("\n\n");

                System.out.println("  Bienvenidos a su Banco PCA  ");
                System.out.println("      MENU TRANSACCIONES      ");
                System.out.println("      1-Depositar Dinero:  ");
                System.out.println("      2-Retirar Dinero    ");
                System.out.println("      3-Consultar Saldo       ");
                System.out.println("      4-Cambio de clave       ");
                System.out.println("      5-Transferir dinero a otra cuenta       ");
                System.out.println(" 5-Regresar al menu principal ");

                System.out.print("Digite opcion...:");
                op1 = sc.nextInt();
                switch (op1) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Depositos");

                    // Validar que el número de cuenta existe
                    boolean existe = false;

                    do {
                        System.out.println("Número de cuenta que recibirá el depósito: ");
                        int numeroCuenta = sc.nextInt();

                        for (Cuenta cuentaActual : cuentas) {

                            // Si existe
                            if (cuentaActual.getNumeroCuenta() == numeroCuenta) {
                                existe = true;

                                System.out.println("Monto: ");
                                double monto = sc.nextDouble();

                                double saldoActualizado = cuentaActual.getSaldo() + monto;

                                System.out.println("Saldo actualizado. Antes: " + cuentaActual.getSaldo() + ", ahora: " + saldoActualizado);

                                // Actualizar saldo
                                cuentaActual.setSaldo(saldoActualizado);
                            }
                        }

                        // Si no existe
                        if (existe == false) {
                            System.out.println("Cuenta no encontrada. Intentelo nuevamente...");
                        }

                    } while (existe == false);

                    System.out.println("Pulse cualquier numero y Enter para continuar...");
                    op1 = sc.nextInt();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Retiros");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Consulta de saldo");
                    break;

                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Cambio de clave");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Transferir dinero a otra cuenta");

                    // Validar que el número de cuenta que enviará el dinero existe
                    boolean existeEnviara = false;
                    int indexCuentaEnviara = 0;

                    do {
                        System.out.println("Número de cuenta que enviará el dinero: ");
                        int numeroCuentaEnviara = sc.nextInt();

                        for (int i = 0; i < cuentas.size(); i++) {
                            if (cuentas.get(i).getNumeroCuenta() == numeroCuentaEnviara) {
                                existeEnviara = true;

                                // Guardar posición de la cuenta
                                // La usaremos más adelante para saber a cuál cuenta restarle dinero
                                indexCuentaEnviara = i;
                            }
                        }

                        // Si no existe avisar al usuario
                        if (existeEnviara == false) {
                            System.out.println("Cuenta no encontrada. Intentelo nuevamente...");
                        }

                    } while (existeEnviara == false);

                    // Validar que el número de cuenta que recibirá el dinero existe
                    boolean existeRecibira = false;
                    int indexCuentaRecibira = 0;

                    do {
                        System.out.println("Número de cuenta que recibirá el dinero: ");
                        int numeroCuentaEnviara = sc.nextInt();

                        for (int i = 0; i < cuentas.size(); i++) {
                            if (cuentas.get(i).getNumeroCuenta() == numeroCuentaEnviara) {
                                existeRecibira = true;

                                // Guardar posición de la cuenta
                                // La usaremos más adelante para saber a cuál cuenta sumarle dinero
                                indexCuentaRecibira = i;
                            }
                        }

                        // Si no existe
                        if (existeRecibira == false) {
                            System.out.println("Cuenta no encontrada. Intentelo nuevamente...");
                        }

                    } while (existeRecibira == false);

                    /**
                     * Preguntar el monto
                     * Debitaremos este monto a la cuenta que enviará
                     * Sumaremos el monto a la cuenta que recibirá
                     * Debemos validar que la cuenta tenga balance suficiente
                     */
                    boolean balanceSuficiente = false;
                    do {
                        System.out.println("Monto a transferir: ");
                        double montoParaTransferir = sc.nextDouble();

                        // Si la cuenta tiene un saldo mayor o igual que el monto a transferir
                        if (cuentas.get(indexCuentaEnviara).getSaldo() >= montoParaTransferir) {
                            balanceSuficiente = true;

                            // Restar de la cuenta que envía
                            double saldoActual = cuentas.get(indexCuentaEnviara).getSaldo();
                            System.out.println("La cuenta número " + cuentas.get(indexCuentaEnviara).getNumeroCuenta() + " tenía $" + saldoActual + " y ahora tiene $" + (saldoActual - montoParaTransferir));
                            saldoActual = saldoActual - montoParaTransferir;
                            cuentas.get(indexCuentaEnviara).setSaldo(saldoActual);

                            // Sumar monto a la cuenta que recibe
                            double saldoActual2 = cuentas.get(indexCuentaRecibira).getSaldo();
                            System.out.println("La cuenta número " + cuentas.get(indexCuentaRecibira).getNumeroCuenta() + " tenía $" + saldoActual2 + " y ahora tiene $" + (saldoActual2 + montoParaTransferir));
                            saldoActual2 = saldoActual2 + montoParaTransferir;
                            cuentas.get(indexCuentaRecibira).setSaldo(saldoActual2);
                        } else { // Si no tiene el monto disponible
                            System.out.println("La cuenta no tiene $" + montoParaTransferir + " disponible. Intente otro...");
                        }
                    } while (balanceSuficiente == false);

                    System.out.println("Pulse cualquier numero y Enter para continuar...");
                    op1 = sc.nextInt();
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Opcion no valida... Intente nuevamente");
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 3: // Detalles de cuentas existentes
                // Imprimir información de todas las cuentas existentes
                System.out.println("\nCantidad de cuentas existentes: " + cuentas.size());

                for (Cuenta cuentaActual : cuentas) {
                    System.out.println("----------");
                    System.out.println("Número de cuenta: " + cuentaActual.getNumeroCuenta());
                    System.out.println("Nombre: " + cuentaActual.getNombre());
                    System.out.println("Documento: " + cuentaActual.getDocumento());
                    System.out.println("Saldo: " + cuentaActual.getSaldo());
                    System.out.println("Clave: " + cuentaActual.getClave());
                    System.out.println("----------");
                }

                System.out.println("Pulse cualquier numero y Enter para continuar...");
                op1 = sc.nextInt();
                break;
            }
        } while (op != 4); // Cambiado a 4

        sc.close(); // Cerrar Scanner
        System.out.println("Gracias por utilizar nuestros servicios...Hasta Pronto.");
    }
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos!.

Comment: siento tener que hacer esto, pero por favor la ultima ayuda, ya pude hacer lo de depositar, consultar y retirar saldo, pero lo unico que no se como hacer es transferir dinero de una cuenta a otra porque no se como hacerlo

Comment: @juanito Hola amigo, te he ayudado y he editado mi respuesta con el código necesario. Lo he comentado para que puedas entender paso por paso lo que he hecho. Podrás retirar saldo de una cuenta y depositar ese saldo a otra, validando que la cuenta que envía tenga balance disponible. Espero haberte ayudado, saludos!.